# how to stream from kafka to cassandra and increment counters

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have apache access log file and i want to store access counts (total/daily/hourly) of each page in a cassandra table.

I am trying to do it by using kafka connect to stream from log file to a kafka topic. In order to increment metrics counters in Cassandra can I use Kafka Connect again? Otherwise which other tool should be used here e.g. kafka streams, spark, flink, kafka connect etc?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the guides on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

You're talking about doing stream processing, which Kafka can do - either with [Kafka's Streams API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/), or [KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-open-source-streaming-sql-for-apache-kafka/). KSQL runs on top of Kafka Streams, and gives you a very simple way to build the kind of aggregations that you're talking about.

Here's an example of doing aggregations of streams of data in KSQL

```
SELECT PAGE_ID,COUNT(*) FROM PAGE_CLICKS WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 HOUR) GROUP BY PAGE_ID
```

See more at : https://www.confluent.io/blog/using-ksql-to-analyse-query-and-transform-data-in-kafka

You can take the output of KSQL which is actually just a Kafka topic, and stream that through Kafka Connect e.g. to Elasticsearch, Cassandra, and so on.

You mention other stream processing tools, they're valid too - depends in part on existing skills and language preferences (e.g. Kafka Streams is Java library, KSQL is … KSQL, Spark Streaming has Python as well as Java, etc), but also deployment preferences. Kafka Streams is just a Java library to deploy within your existing application. KSQL is deployable in a cluster, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with Flink, either as a batch or streaming job, and either with or without Kafka (Flink can read from files and write to Cassandra). This sort of time windowed aggregation is easily done with Flink's SQL api; see the [examples here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/table/streaming.html).